# How can I say "don't take it personally"?

Tags: translation

Expressions are often difficult to translate. Word-by-word isn't always comprehensible. Does "ne prenu tion persone" work for this one?

- *He criticizes everyone, don't take it personally.*
- *Don't take it personally, but I'm not interested in a relationship right now.*
- *You shouldn't take the reactions personally; the problem is the company, not you.*

Answer (score 8):

*Ne prenu tion persone* is likely to be interpreted as *Don't pick that up yourself*, (i.e. "don't deal with it yourself") which is not quite what you want. Try *Ne komprenu (ĉi tion) kiel insulton/riproĉon* or *aludon al vi*.

- *Li kritikas ĉiujn; ne temas pri vi persone.*
- *Ne temas nur pri vi kiam mi diras ke mi ne deziras amaĵon nuntempe.*
- *Vi devus ne interpreti la reagojn kiel atakojn al vi persone; la problemo estas la firmao, ne vi.*